# PayPal - What if a Billing Plan is made INACTIVE having a few billing-aggrement approved already?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

For Paypal, when a Billing Plan's state is set to "INACTIVE", does that mean the billing agreements that were approved/executed for this plan are also canceled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the state of the billing plans is set to "INACTIVE" it just means that you cannot create new billing agreements with this plan. This is not going to affect existing billing agreements.